# Django - Models - Custom User who Inherites from built-in User

Tags: django, models

I created `CustomUser` class and `CustomUser` has a foreign key to the built-in `User` class:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In `.html` (template) I wish to call the website variable, like: `{{user.website}}`. Unfortunately it doesn't work, but `{{user}}` and `{{user.username}}` works.

Another issue is that I want to have relationship with Post by User, so inside template .html I want to show specific user and his all posts

I built already `Post` model, but I don't know how to call to specific user's posts. I am sure if you can explain how to call to `"website"`, I will do the same to `post/user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the one-to-one (profile) method for extending the user class, you have to specify the profile class, such as:

```
{{ user.customuser.website }}
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) on various ways to extend the `User` model.

Comment: True, but how Django knows about "customuser", I tried CustomUser and it didn't work, I declared class CustomUser, not customuser, how does django know about it. I need explanation to fully understand

Comment: Django uses the lowercase version of the class name when you don't explicitly specify it using a `related_name` argument. See the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield